# Set offset limit in react native scrollview

Tags: react-native

I have a horizontal ScrollView in react native. This ScrollView contains two elements. For the sake of simplicity lets call these elements `blue` and `green`.

[image]

Over the `ScrollView` I also have absolutly positioned `View` which I can drag left and right.

[image]

What I want to achieve is that when I'm scrolling the scrollview from left to right, the blue area should not pass the purple View. Scrolling should just stop in the right hand direction. Scrolling to the left must work as usually.

One solution I can think of is to make the blue area very wide and then set the min offset to the scrollview based on the position of purple draggable view. But I'm not sure if it's doable with `ScrollView`

```
<ScrollView
  ...
  minOffset={positionOfThePurpleView}
/>
```

Can anyone think of a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

This is more of an answer for whoever has still this question

In order to reduce the limit of a screen you can limit it using a `<View>` component inside a `Scrollview`

in this case:

```js
<ScrollView>
  <View style = {{width: (your limit here)}}>
    code here
  </View>
</ScrollView>
```

in case you want to adjust the height

```js
<ScrollView>
  <View style = {{height: (your limit here)}}>
    code here
  </View>
</ScrollView>
```

Hope it works for someone